Qwen 2.5 7B randomly hangs for 67 minutes when called using Ollama while running on EC2 Instance
I have Qwen 2.5 7B installed on an EC2 instance - currently a C7i.8Xlarge - and am running a series of data driven prompts through it. The variables from the prompts are pulled from a dataframe.  I am using Ollama invoke to call the model.  As the script iterates through the rows in the dataframe, each call to Qwen typically takes 20 seconds - sometimes as low as 6 seconds and sometimes as long as 57 seconds.  And then sometimes it will hang for 1 hour and 7 minutes. And when I say 1 hour 7 minutes, I mean repeatably that exact time (observed running large batches overnight). I set a timeout of 59 seconds using the Ollama model definition:
`llm = Ollama(
     model = "qwen2.5:latest",
     temperature = 0.3,
     timeout = 59
)`

When I set the timeout to 10 seconds, about 2/3 of a test batch timed out so that seems to be functioning correctly and I bumped it up to 59 seconds to cover my order population. I have run the same data (500+ rows) using the exact same code against Mistral 7B, Llama3.1 8B, Llama3.2 3B and have not had any issues.  1 hour and 7 minutes is 4020 seconds, which makes me wonder if there is a 4000 second timeout somewhere that I could hopefully set to a lower value.  The specific orders that hang are inconsistent from run to run and while the length of these prompts are on the upper end of my overall population, they are not the longest (and the prompts are nowhere near the token limit.  Any thoughts as to why I am getting a random 4020 second timeout?
Edit:  I have yet to identify root cause or solve directly but have implemented a work around by putting the model call into a function and using signal to timeout when it hangs. It isn't elegant but it allows me to run large batches for analysis without worrying about 1hour+ hangs on orders.  Here is how I worked around my issue: Timeout on a function call
